# Array item numbers for consecutive items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a seat booking system which links to a CSV file and checks whether seating is available based on user input (seats together required and row number).

The row specified by the user is then retrieved as `line`. B would return:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'B']
```

Where 0 is a free seat and 1 is a taken seat. The letter identifies the row.

I'm using the below line to retrieve the largest amount of consecutive zeroes in the array giving the largest block of seats.

```
LargeBlock = max(sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(line) if k == '0')
```

I'd also like to return seat numbers. So using the above example, if a user requested three seats on row B, it would output B1-B3 being available. Any ideas on how to retrieve the numbers of the items in the list based on both the user input and the LargeBlock variable?

Comment: Please take a second a re-read what your wrote and try to be clearer to the people who are not in the thick of this problem. I don't understand how the array related to the block seat coding system.

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral: I am slightly puzzled by your comment. I find the question crystal clear.

Comment: My apologies. ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'B'] doesn't mean to much to me. Maybe I just need to re-read this again.

Comment: I am with you Victor. I can guess 0 and 1, is B the row letter identifier? or what?

Comment: @Avempace 0 represents a free seat, 1 represents a taken seat and B is the row letter identifier.

Comment: So the row `B` has 10 seats, and the second from the right is taken? That’s not a good way to encode that…

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @poke the project requires me to use a pre-made file, I haven't created the structure. Python 3, yes :).

Comment: Not exactly an implementation question but I have to ask, why return "B1-B4" and not, say, "B4-B7" for four seats on row B? I think most people would prefer center-most seats.

Comment: @nwk Trying to focus on simplicity at the moment and looking at wherever the seats are available as opposed to positioning on the row itself :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, finding the largest free group of seats is not really that useful. For example, a two people could fit into a gap of two seats, and they might prefer those over having a spot in that other group of six consecutive seats. And as you want to get the machine full, you probably want to prefer filling those hard-to-fill slots early too before you start getting spots from those larger free group areas.

So instead of getting you the biggest group, my solution just gives you *every* combination of seats you can take in a row.

```
def getPossibleSeats (line, row, num):
    if row != line[-1]:
        raise ValueError('Invalid row')

    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(line[:-1], 1), lambda x: x[1]):
        g = list(g)
        if k != '0' or len(g) < num:
            continue

        for i in range(len(g) - num + 1):
            yield ['{}{}'.format(row, s) for s, _ in g[i:i+num]]
```

For your example line, it looks like this:

```
>>> line = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'B']
>>> for seats in getPossibleSeats(line, 'B', 4):
        print(seats)

['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']
['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']
['B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6']
['B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']
```

For another example, it may look like this:

```
>>> line = list('11000110000001C')
>>> for seats in getPossibleSeats(line, 'C', 2):
        print(seats)

['C3', 'C4']
['C4', 'C5']
['C8', 'C9']
['C9', 'C10']
['C10', 'C11']
['C11', 'C12']
['C12', 'C13']
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming is your friend!

You can define a utility function that gives you a new row with each seat listing how many free sits are there *to the left* of the given sit:

```python
def free_seats(row):
    seats = []
    seats.append(1 if row[0] == '0' else 0)
    for k in range(1, len(row)):
        seats.append(0 if row[k] == '1' else 1 + seats[k-1])
    return seats
```

Then you use the number of free sits to find the first possible placement with the row code:

```python
def find_n_seats(n, line):
    row_code = line[-1]
    available_seats = free_seats(line[:-1]) # Remove the line code
    try:
        last_seat = available_seat.index(n)
        return [row_code + str(i+1) for i in range(last_seat + 1 - n, last_seat)]
    except ValueError:
        print('Not possible to find {0} seats in row {1}'.format(n, row_code))
        return None
```

The above function should be applied to each line until you find a match.